# Jooq and generic condition generator in scala

Tags: scala, jooq

I need to generate jooq Condition in scala. Values could be `Long` or `java.math.BigDecimal`
Compilation fails, don't fully understand if it's do-able or not

generic method

```scala
  private def genericValueFilterCondition[T: ClassTag](filters: List[(ValueFilter, List[T])])(implicit m: Manifest[T]): Condition = {
    filters.foldLeft(DSL.noCondition()) { (cond, filterAndValues) =>
      val (f, values) = filters
      f.operator match {
        // some cases omitted for brevity 
        case ValueOperator.LESS =>
          cond.and(field(f.valueDef.name, m.runtimeClass).lessThan(values.head))
        case ValueOperator.EQUAL if f.values.size > 1 =>
          cond.and(field(f.valueDef.name, m.runtimeClass).in(values: _*))
    
      }
    }
  }
```

invocation

```scala
    genericValueFilterCondition[Long](longValues.map(f => f -> f.values.map(_.toLong))).and(
      genericValueFilterCondition[java.math.BigDecimal](decimalValues.map(f => f -> f.values.map(v => toJavaBigDecimal(v))))
```

compilation error:

```
overloaded method value lessThan with alternatives:
  (x$1: org.jooq.QuantifiedSelect[_ <: org.jooq.Record1[_$1]])org.jooq.Condition <and>
  (x$1: org.jooq.Select[_ <: org.jooq.Record1[_$1]])org.jooq.Condition <and>
  (x$1: org.jooq.Field[_$1])org.jooq.Condition <and>
  (x$1: _$1)org.jooq.Condition
 cannot be applied to (T)
...


overloaded method value in with alternatives:
  (x$1: org.jooq.Select[_ <: org.jooq.Record1[_$1]])org.jooq.Condition <and>
  (x$1: org.jooq.Field[_]*)org.jooq.Condition <and>
  (x$1: _$1*)org.jooq.Condition <and>
  (x$1: org.jooq.Result[_ <: org.jooq.Record1[_$1]])org.jooq.Condition <and>
  (x$1: java.util.Collection[_])org.jooq.Condition
 cannot be applied to (T)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my understanding, [`Manifest[T].runtimeClass`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/reflect/Manifest.html#runtimeClass-0) produces `Class[_]`, not `Class[T]`. Cast it to `Class[T]` and you should be fine:

```scala
field(f.valueDef.name, m.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]])
```